# Item with same id already exists

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to join tables using on a collection on magento 1.9,but it throws exception saying item with same id already exists.

I have been trying join tables using collection in magento 1.9,When I print the raw sql and execute the same in any mysql editor the query runs successfully.
But,when tried programmatically it throws exception saying 'Exception' with message 'Item (Package_Module_Model_Settings) with the same id "2" already exist'

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('package/tablename1')->getCollection();
 $collection->getSelect()
                    ->join(array('t2' => 'package_tablename2'), 
                      't2.id=main_table.columnname')
                    ->where("t2.columnname='abc'");
```

how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with "Group By" function as below.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('package/tablename1')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
                ->join(array('t2' => 'package_tablename2'), 
                  't2.id=main_table.columnname')
                ->where("t2.columnname='abc'")
                ->group('main_table.columnname');
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: please share your SQL query.You can get this by   "echo $collection->getSelect();".

Comment: SELECT `main_table`.*, `e`.* FROM `rewards_settings` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `rewards_eventnames` AS `e` ON  main_table.eventnames_no=e.id WHERE (e.event_name='abc');

Comment: Please try follow query i think you missing group function.

"SELECT main_table.*, e.* FROM rewards_settings AS main_table INNER JOIN rewards_eventnames AS e ON main_table.eventnames_no=e.id WHERE (e.event_name='abc') GROUP BY main_table.eventnames_no;"